# How to save a function with python (3.2)

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

Just started learning python (3.2) and have a question. I have created a some code that creates some stats (as in health, magic etc etc) and the numbers are randomly generated. Here is the code...

```
def stats ():
print ()
print ('Some text.')

done = False
while not done :
charname = input(str('What is the name of the character? '))

hp = random.randint(5,20)
mp = random.randint(4,20)
stre = random.randint(3,20)
agi = random.randint(3,20)
spd = random.randint(3,20)
wis = random.randint(3,20)
intel = random.randint(3,20)
cha = random.randint(3,20)

print (charname)
print ('HP:',hp)
print ('Mana:',mp)
print ('Strength:',stre)
print ('Agility:',agi)
print ('Speed:',spd)
print ('Wisdom:',wis)
print ('Intelligence:',intel)
print ('Charisma:',cha)
print ()


done = input('All done? yes/no ')
if( done == 'yes' ):
    done = True
elif(done == 'no'):
    done = False



while done :
print ()
print ('Now that your stats are done, you can go on your adventure!')
done = False
```

Now this works fine, but how could I call on this function again in case I wanted to view the stats again with it keeping the same stats it randomly generated before?

Sorry if the question is bit off. Still all new to programming.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you fix the formatting of your code?  It's difficult to tell what you're starting with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're new to programming, here's some advice on a different way to store your data (without actually coding it for you).

First, define a `Character` class, with attributes for HP, mana, etc. I don't know if you know about classes yet, but [here's an intro](http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/iterators.html#defining-classes). There are various tricks you can do to get around having to explicitly write in the names for HP, mana, etc, but for learning's sake, it's probably better to do them all manually for now.

Then `def` a `random_character()` function that creates a `Character` object with random attributes, defined like how you're doing now, but instead of saving them in different variables that Python doesn't know have anything to do with one another, puts them in a single `Character`.

Add a `__str__` method to the `Character` class, so that if `char` is a `Character`, `print(char)` prints out the attributes.

If you want to be able to keep track of characters, use [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/pickle.html) to store it in files.

If you have questions about any part of this, just ask. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your function now uses local variables to record the stats you've generated.  You'll need to bundle them together into either a dictionary or an object so that you can pass them around as a value.

For example:

```
def get_stats():
    stats = {}
    stats['charname'] = input(str('What is the name of the character? '))

    stats['hp'] = random.randint(5,20)
    stats['mp'] = random.randint(4,20)
    stats['stre'] = random.randint(3,20)
    stats['agi'] = random.randint(3,20)
    stats['spd'] = random.randint(3,20)
    stats['wis'] = random.randint(3,20)
    stats['intel'] = random.randint(3,20)
    stats['cha'] = random.randint(3,20)

    return stats

def print_stats(stats):
    print (stats['charname'])
    print ('HP:',stats['hp'])
    print ('Mana:',stats['mp'])
    print ('Strength:',stats['stre'])
    print ('Agility:',stats['agi'])
    print ('Speed:',stats['spd'])
    print ('Wisdom:',stats['wis'])
    print ('Intelligence:',stats['intel'])
    print ('Charisma:',stats['cha'])
    print ()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `def` keyword to declare functions . [Def](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/functions.html)

```
def stat():
```

you can call the function like this in your desired location.  `stat()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want easy storage in an external file, you can use the `pickle` module, and a dictionary of the values you wish to store.

for example:

```
import pickle
stats={}
stats['hp'] = random.randint(5,20)
stats['mp'] = random.randint(4,20)
stats['stre'] = random.randint(3,20)
stats['agi'] = random.randint(3,20)
stats['spd'] = random.randint(3,20)
stats['wis'] = random.randint(3,20)
stats['intel'] = random.randint(3,20)
stats['cha'] = random.randint(3,20)
#save the stats into the file by using:
pickle.dump(stats,yourstatfile.pkl)
#then to load it again from any program just use:
stats=pickle.load(yourstatfile.pkl) #you assign it to a variable, so if i used the variable 'lol' i would use it as lol['hp'] not stats['hp'] like it was originally used when saving.
#then you can use it just like any other dictionary:
print "your hp: "+str(stats['hp'])
```